# Bitarray C# serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, console

Serialization:

```
            bool[] tempArray = new bool[MapWidth * MapHeight];
            for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
            {
                for (int ii = 0; ii < MapHeight; ii++)
                {
                    tempArray[i * ii] = mapSolid[i, ii];
                }
            }
            BitArray bits = new BitArray(tempArray);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[32 * MapWidth];
            bits.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
            bin.Serialize(stream, Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
```

Desrialization:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[255 * 255];
                    bytes=Convert.FromBase64String((string)bin.Deserialize(stream));
                    //mapSolid = ;
                    MapWidth = (int)bin.Deserialize(stream);
                    MapHeight = (int)bin.Deserialize(stream);
                    BitArray bits = new BitArray(bytes);
                    bool[] bytestemp = new bool[255*265];
                    bits.CopyTo(bytestemp, 0);
                    for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
                    {
                        for (int ii = 0; ii < MapHeight; ii++)
                        {
                            mapSolid[i, ii] = bytestemp[i*ii];
                        }
                    }
```

Now everything seems to work without errors but the map looses it's structure after deserialization.

Comment: Please show sample input data and expected output

Comment: what does "looses it's structure" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tempArray[i * ii]
```

and

```
bytestemp[i * ii]
```

is wrong; that index should be something like:

```
(i * MapWidth) + ii
```

or

```
i + (ii * MapHeight)
```

depending on whether you are writing rows-first or columns-first.

Otherwise, for example, the cells {1,4} and {4,1} would be stored *in the same place*.

If you want to avoid the math, another common approach is just:

```
int offset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < MapHeight; ii++)
    {
        tempArray[offset++] = mapSolid[i, ii];
    }
}
```

and

```
int offset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < MapHeight; ii++)
    {
        mapSolid[i, ii] = bytestemp[offset++];
    }
}
```

i.e. just read/write from/to "the next position" each time. Just make sure the read and write loop agree on which is the outer/inner loop (they seem to).

Comment: @Max0999 I still say a large `bool[,]` array is not a great approach...